# Making "Next" button work in a picture organizer

Tags: c#, image

I am currently working on a small project in C# regarding the arrangement of some pictures. This project is going to contain several features which I will try to solve myself. The thing is that I got stuck ...right at the beginning to my embarrassment.
So far I have these lines of code done :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = pictureBox1.InitialImage;
        }


    }
```

So ,the first button is going to make me able to load a picture. That works. The thing is that i do not know how to make the "Next picture button"(Button2) work. I have been searching on all websites,including this one for 3 hours yesterday but could not find a solution,at least not a " Button click" one. I have a folder full of pictures, 500+ and I want to organize them by category,a feature I will add later. What I want the "Next" button to do is the following. I press button1,I choose the first picture and the NEXT (button2) just goes to the 2nd,press again and shows the 3rd ,again 4th ,...etc.

I really burnt my brains on this one and I just can`t figure it out.

P.S: The line on button2 is just some things i tried.

I know it is not much work (that I have done) but for a beginner I hope it`s enough.

Thank you a lot for your time as I had questions answered before!

Comment: What do you mean by "go to the next picture"?  The first button appears to be opening a single file, not a list of files.  Maybe the first button should open a *directory* instead of a file?  Then you can get the list of files in that directory, filter for the ones you want, and keep them in a list in the program.  Then "next" would simply move to the next element in that list.

Comment: @David ok...I honestly havent thought of that. I will give it a try but how does the filter work? I just want it to jump to the next picture ,sure with a file list it will work...I just dont **see** it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an `OpenFileDialog`, use [a `FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This will allow the user to select a folder containing files, not just a single file.  (So the user has some expectation that the operation will involve the whole folder, which is good.)

From that dialog, you can use the `SelectedPath` property to get a directory listing.  Something like:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
```

In fact, might as well make `files` a class-level member:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    IList<string> files;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

        this.files = new List<string>();
    }

    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath).ToList();
    }

}
```

Now `files` is a list of file names.  Keep in mind it will be *all* files in the folder, so you might want to filter it a bit.  A [search pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can help with that, or you could even filter the list manually after you've fetched it to apply more complex logic.

You can enumerate that list all you like.  For example, maybe you store the current index as well:

```
IList<string> files;
int currentFileIndex = 0;
```

Then display the "current" file any time you like:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = files[currentFileIndex];
```

And move to the next one any time you like (remembering to reset it to the first index if it reaches the end):

```
currentFileIndex++;
if (currentFileIndex >= files.Count)
    currentFileIndex = 0;
```

Comment: To my surprise I understood all that...thought I wouldnt at first sight. Still I cant get rid of an error it shows me `The name "Directory" does not exist in the current context` I feel that I should change it with something else...Anyway Thank you a lot for helping me. And for your time.

Comment: @Maiels: You probably just need to add `using System.IO` to the top of the file.

Comment: Of course! Thank you! I suppose that the last line of code (`currentFileInder++;` etc) is for resetting the index right?

Comment: @Maiels: Correct.  There may even be a more elegant way to do that, but this seems simple enough.  I'd probably end up creating a custom object to encapsulate that indexing logic and just have it provide the "next" file, but that's likely not necessary in this case.  You can make it cleaner and more elegant over time as you see fit.